# Return UI components from functions in react-native

Tags: react-native

The following code is working fine

```
<View>
    <ViewShot ref={viewShotRef}>
            <Grayscale >
                <Image style={styles.imgstyle}
                    source={{ uri: sourceImage, }}
                    onLoadEnd={onImageLoaded}
                />
            </Grayscale>
    </ViewShot>
</View>
```

I tried to render some of the UI in a function

```
const renderFilter = () => {
return(
 <Grayscale >
                <Image style={styles.imgstyle}
                    source={{ uri: sourceImage, }}
                    onLoadEnd={onImageLoaded}
                />
  </Grayscale>
)
}

<View>
    <ViewShot ref={viewShotRef}>
            renderFilter()
    </ViewShot>
</View>
```

But I got an error. Not sure from where exactly the error is coming.

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a function inside a JSX block without using curly braces. The following will fix your issue.

```js
<View>
    <ViewShot ref={viewShotRef}>
      {renderFilter()}
    </ViewShot>
</View>
```